# Accessing SQL Server Remotely - Connection fails when attempting to connect with new external domain

Tags: windows, sql, ssms

The Scenario is:

Right now, we can remotely access SQL server using SSMS or a ODBC connection using the SQL driver.
We are currently using **sql1.mydomain.com**

We are switching to **sql2.mydomain.com**. When I attempt to connect with SSMS, I get the following error:

### Connect to Server

Cannot connect to sql2.mydomain.com.

---

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=258&LinkId=20476

---

The wait operation timed out

---

If I ping sql1.mydomain.com and sql2.mydomain.com, I get the same IP address, so I know the DNS Entry is pointed correctly.

Is SQL server configured somehow to only accept connections from sql1.mydomain.com, or is there something else that could be causing this?

I also want to note that we have other rules in place, such as RDP and security cameras, that work fine with the new hostname. Seems like just SQL doesn't like this.

Comment: Are you perhaps using Named Instances with hostname mapping?

Answer (score 0):

It was a port forwarding rule that needed to be adjusted.